# How are basis elements also elements of the topology?

Tags: general-topology

I read the following definitions in Munkres' *Topology* (2nd Edition):

> If $X$ is a set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection
>   $\mathcal B$ of subsets of $X$ (called basis elements) such that
>
> 1. For each $x\in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$.
> 2. If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that
>      $B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$.
>
> If $\mathcal B$ satisfies these two conditions, then we define the
>   topology $\mathcal T$ generated by $\mathcal B$ as follows: A subset
>   $U$ of $X$ is said to be open in $X$ (that is, to be an element of
>   $\mathcal T$) if for each $x\in U$, there is a basis element
>   $B\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in B$ and $B\subset U$. **Note that each
>   basis element is itself an element of $\mathcal T$.**

From this, I am having difficulties understanding how the last sentence follows. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: If $U \in \mathcal{B}$, then you can pick $B = U$ in the criterion.

Comment: +1 It follows by definition. For some reason I thought that I had to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding on Daniel Fischer's comment a bit:

From the definition of an open set from a basis, we have:

> A subset $U$ of $X$ is said to be open iff for each $x\in U$, there is a basis element $B\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$.

So consider this:

Take a $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and further let $x\in B$.

There exists a basis element, namely $B$, such that:

$x \in B \subseteq B$,

and hence $B$ is open.